# Register Basic Auth in Selenium 4 BiDi API with Python WebDriver

Tags: python, authentication, selenium-webdriver

I can do basic auth in Python using the Selenium Web Driver by embedding the credentials in the URL:

```html
driver.get(f'https://{ACCESS_USERNAME}:{ACCESS_PASSWORD}@{TEST_URL}')
```

Selenium 4 introduces the BiDi API with a Register Basic Auth option.  This allows registering a username and password for a site instead of using the above.  In the documentation here:
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/

All the supported languages save Python have an example.  When I try similar things to the Ruby example, I don't see any similar methods in Python.  Is this supported in Python?  Could someone provide/point me to an example?

***PLEASE NOTE:***  Before marking this as a duplicate - this option has only been available since October of 2021.  I couldn't find anything similar - all the candidates are from years ago and not about Selenium 4 (released October, 2021).  If you find something similar, please make sure it's about Selenium 4!

Thank you in advance.

---

Update:
From looking at other WebDriver languages and examples, one option might be to use the DevTools protocol and add an Authorization header.  For example, I can build a basic authorization header:

```py
from base64 import b64encode
username = 'example'
password = 'example'
creds = b64encode(bytes(f'{username}:{password}', encoding='utf8'))
# Note:  DevTools won't take binary data so must convert from bytes:
header = f'Basic {creds.decode("utf8")}'
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders', {'Authorization': header})
```

I tried a few variations, but I keep getting a traceback:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 179, in execute_cdp_cmd
    return self.execute("executeCdpCommand", {'cmd': cmd, 'params': cmd_args})['value']
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: Invalid parameters
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.110)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x01116903+2517251]
(...)
```

Am I on the right track?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. I resolved this issue as below. Things to be noted

1. We need to encode as byte(encode("ascii")), encode to base64(b64encode), credentials and then decode as string (decode("ascii")) - Note - This encode ascii convert string to bytes, similar way the decode("ascii") will decode the bytes to string.
2. We need to convert the authorization as network.header (network.Headers(auth_dict)) to work. Simple headers will not work.

   ```
   from selenium.webdriver.common.devtools.v104 import network
   from selenium import webdriver
   import base64
   authorization = 
   base64.b64encode("username:password".encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
   auth_dict = {'Authorization': f"Basic {authorization}"}
   params = ({
       "headers": network.Headers(auth_dict)
   })
   driver:webdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.enable', {})
   driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setExtraHTTPHeaders', params)
   driver.get('https://basic-authentication-portal')
   ```

I followed this way it worked for me. One thing to be noted it will not work for firefox as fixefox not have support for execute_cdp_cmd.